# Unable to change the date-format for duet-date-picker

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using date-picker provided by https://github.com/duetds/date-picker.
By default, it's date format is YYYY-MM-DD, I want to change it to US date format that is MM/DD/YYYY.
I tried every possible way mentioned on the site as well as went through all Issues reported under Github related to date format, however I am still unable to change it easily.

```
<duet-date-picker name="date" language="en" label="Choose a date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="2020-06-16"></duet-date-picker>

<script>
    const picker = document.querySelector("duet-date-picker")
    const DATE_FORMAT_US = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/

    picker.dateAdapter = {
        parse(value = "", createDate) {
            const matches = value.match(DATE_FORMAT_US)

            if (matches) {
                return createDate(matches[3], matches[1], matches[2])
            }
        },
        format(date) {
            return `${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`
        },
    }

    picker.localization = {
        buttonLabel: "Choose date",
        placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy",
        selectedDateMessage: "Selected date is",
        prevMonthLabel: "Previous month",
        nextMonthLabel: "Next month",
        monthSelectLabel: "Month",
        yearSelectLabel: "Year",
        closeLabel: "Close window",
        calendarHeading: "Choose a date",
        dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
        monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
        monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        locale: "en-US",
    }
```

Comment: Can you put than in JSFiddle?

Comment: [It works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/qejnk5L4/). I think you maybe forgot to link duet.esm.js script.

Comment: Yes, I have included it as given below:

<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@duetds/date-picker@1.4.0/dist/duet/duet.esm.js"></script>
<script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@duetds/date-picker@1.4.0/dist/duet/duet.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@duetds/date-picker@1.4.0/dist/duet/themes/default.css" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow localization was not getting set correctly, hence decided to use below syntax to make sure localization is getting set only after complete DOM is loaded.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { 
        const picker1 = document.querySelector(".date1")
        const DATE_FORMAT_US = /^(\d{1,2})\/(\d{1,2})\/(\d{4})$/

        picker1.dateAdapter = {
            parse(value = "", createDate) {
                const matches = value.match(DATE_FORMAT_US)

                if (matches) {
                    return createDate(matches[3], matches[1], matches[2])
                }
            },
            format(date) {
                return `${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`
            },
        }

        picker1.localization = {
            buttonLabel: "Choose date",
            placeholder: "mm/dd/yyyy",
            selectedDateMessage: "Selected date is",
            prevMonthLabel: "Previous month",
            nextMonthLabel: "Next month",
            monthSelectLabel: "Month",
            yearSelectLabel: "Year",
            closeLabel: "Close window",
            calendarHeading: "Choose a date",
            dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
            monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
            monthNamesShort: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
            locale: "en-US",
        }
    });
```

```html
<script type="module" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@duetds/date-picker@1.4.0/dist/duet/duet.esm.js"></script>
    <script nomodule src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@duetds/date-picker@1.4.0/dist/duet/duet.js"></script>

    
<duet-date-picker class="date1" name="date" language="en" label="Choose a date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" value="2020-06-16"></duet-date-picker>
```